# OCI ObjectStorage -- How to enable CORS for a bucket?

Tags: oracle, cors, object-storage, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I need help in figuring out how to enable CORS (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) on an object-storage bucket please?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, Cross-Origin-Resource sharing is enabled for OCI ObjectStorage native & Swift API.

```
➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ curl -I https://objectstorage.us-phoenix-1.oraclecloud.com
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Wed, 12 Dec 2018 01:52:00 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
opc-request-id: 286901e2-4180-812c-2779-18b415009904
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,PUT,GET,HEAD,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Credentials,Access-Control-Allow-Methods,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Connection,opc-client-info,opc-request-id
```

Comment: How can we enable it so that pre signed url can be used from browser AJAX calls>

Comment: this doesn't answer the question at all.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, it seems like Oracle's object storage does not support CORS headers (nor ACLS - shame).

If you are generating pre-signed URLs to files in the private bucket, you could use the "Sec-Fetch-Mode" request header to know if the browser will check CORS for file.

See details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Sec-Fetch-Mode

So you can do the following:

if Sec-Fetch-Mode = cors, you should download the file to your server and then send it to the browser (that way the file origin will be the same as your application).

if it's not, then you can generate a pre-signed URL and redirect the browser to it.

One last thing, IE and Safari browsers will not send the "Sec-Fetch-Mode" header even if they still check for cors, so in their case, the solution of sending the file through your server is to be done.

More about pre-signed URLs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html